# density transformation preserving differentiability and continuity?

Tags: probability, derivatives, transformation

Let X be a continuous r.v. with the density, $f_X(x)$, and let $Y=g(X)$. Suppose $f_X(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are continuously differentiable. Could we prove that the density of Y, $f_Y(y)$, is continuously differentiable? It seems OK if g is one-to-one. How about $X$ is an n-dimensional random vector, $Y$ is an m-dimensional random vector , and $m<n$?

Comment: $Y$ need not even have a density. An extreme case is when $g$ is a constant.

Comment: As Kavi points out, even if $g$ is differentiable, you might end up with a push forward measure that is not absolutely continuous with respect to the dominating measure (Lebesgue, for instance) and thus does not admit a Radon-Nikodym derivative, or a "density".